# how to import a QML Component resource in a QML file

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlapplicationengine

I have the following directory structure:

```
ui/
  |- resources.qrc
  |- qml/
    |- main_window_presenter.qml
    |- MyPresenter.qml
```

resources.qrc contents:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/MyPresenter.qml</file>
        <file>qml/main_window_presenter.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

MyPresenter.qml contents:

```
import QtQuick 2.11

FocusScope {
  id: root

  property Item view
  property QtObject model

  Component.onCompleted: {
    root.view.anchors.fill = root
    root.view.focus = true
  }
}
```

main_window_presenter.qml contents:

```
import "."

MyPresenter {
  id: root
}
```

main.cpp contents:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(":/qml/main_window_presenter.qml");

  return app.exec();
}
```

When I run the application I get

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file::/qml/main_window_presenter.qml:1 import "." has no qmldir and no namespace
```

If I delete `import "."` at main_window_presenter.qml I get

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component                                                                                                                             
file::/qml/main_window_presenter.qml:3 MyPresenter is not a type
```

I think I shouldn't need an import statement because they are in the same directory. I am using meson build system with this relevant part in meson.build(exe_moc_headers are defined before):

```
qt5_module = import('qt5')
exe_processed = qt5_module.preprocess(moc_headers : exe_moc_headers, qresources : 'ui/resources.qrc')
```

Comment: QQmlApplicationEngine expects to load a QML whose root is a Window, or ApplicationWindow, and this is not the case.

Comment: @eyllanesc How can I accomplish what I want without QQmlApplicationEngine then?

Comment: use QQuickView.

Comment: @eyllanesc QQuickView works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eyllanesc suggested QQuickView works instead of QQmlApplicationEngine:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQuickView* view{new QQuickView};
  view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///qml/main_window_presenter.qml"));
  view->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

I might have figured it myself if the error message wasn't indicating that type is not found by saying *"MyPresenter is not a type"*. This led me to believe that its a referencing issue.